# Auto-layout constraint not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to place layout constraints on a uiimageview, but no matter what I do the imageView's frame size is returned as width:128.0 height:240.0 when I print it in the console. The imageview actually appears to be of equal height and width when I run my app, but the printout still returns 128.0 and 240.0 I've tried using a 1:1 aspect ratio, I've tried setting different height and width sizes - height & width = 250.0, height & width = 200.0 - but the result is still the same. Ideally I want to accomplish an equal dimensions uiimageview in the center of the screen for all iphone sizes. Below is a screenshot of my most recent attempt:

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing constraint breaks at run time? i.e. entries in your log which say 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, will attempt to recover by breaking constraint'. If so can you share these logs?

Comment: Oh also can you clarify what you mean by 'equal' dimension?

Comment: Is it actually not working on the screen, or just not working when you log the size?

Comment: @GlenT There aren't any constraint breaks. I'm trying to create a circular imageview using imageview.layer.cornerradius = self.imageview.frame.width/2.0 and it's not clipping the bounds properly because the height and width aren't equal. There isn't a 1:1 aspect ratio. By "equal" dimension, I mean I want height and width to be the same size.

Comment: To @Aaron's point, where are you applying the corner radius? Is it after viewDidLayoutSubviews()? If not you might be using the frame before the view been sized/positions based on its constraints.

Comment: @GlenT Yes, Aaron was correct. I've been putting layout modifications in viewDidLoad this entire time. Stupid me, haha. I had no idea viewDidLayoutSubviews even existed. Good to know now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the frame within the wrong method. It's not guaranteed to be updated until `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called, but you're checking it in an earlier method - probably `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I also had to put imageview.layer.cornerRadius = imageview.frame.width/2.0 in this method as well in order to clip imageview bounds into a circle. Thanks again! I've been putting that in viewDidLoad this entire time....Is it common to put all layout modifications in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method?

Comment: If your layout modifications assume all the constraints have taken effect then yes.

Comment: If you want to modify stuff *before* the constraints are applied, put them in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.